# Suggested reading after course in game theory

Tags: game-theory, book-recommendation, economics, applications

I would like to hear some of your recommendations on books/papers or topics to research after having learned the basic vocabulary/mathematical framework of game theory.
I would like to gain some insight into the real world application of it or some more examples of interesting games and their analysis.

Thanks in advance :D

For clarification:
**(my knowledge should be around the level you would have after finishing an undergraduate course in game theory)**

Comment: [On numbers and games](https://www.amazon.com/Numbers-Games-John-H-Conway/dp/1568811276) by J. Conway, for example.

Answer (score 1):

For some nice political/ military applications, see Schelling's The Strategy of Conflict. for some economic applications, Friedman's Oligopoly Theory.